# I got an error 'Unable to detect adb version' after update platform-tools v27.0.1 to v28.0.0

Tags: android, adb

OS : Windows10 64bit

Android Studio : v3.1.2

I have to process my project, but I got an error...

'Unable to detect adb version' after update platform-tools v27.0.1 to v28.0.0.

Do I downgrade? or download adb?

[Edit]

I found platform-tools v27.0.1 files.

https://devfiles.co/download/PDYvOWBg/platform-tools-latest-windows.zip

I could download adb files from above link.

Comment: also upgrade classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle & distributionUrl  with latest version

Comment: @ShivamKumar thank for your comment